# MyTouch bricked

Tags: rom-flashing, crashes, unbricking, htc-mytouch

I have a MyTouch 4G which I had to pull battery on and then when bootup came up, it just sits and hangs at the white logo screen. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to run an ruu if you don't have a custom recovery

You could try rebooting into bootloader and doing a factory reset there (typically, turn device off, hold volume down and power till you're in the bootloader, volume moves, power selects in that screen)

Comment: Are there any examples or tutorials on how to do this? I've never had to do this before.

Comment: It's similar to flashing a custom mod - generally you need to reboot into the bootloader. HTC's bootloaders usually look for a hardcoded filename.